# How to change image's author via a function when using GravityForms uploader?

Tags: images, uploads, author, plugin-gravity-forms

I am wondering if there is a way to manually change the author of images.

I am using Gravity Forms which sets the post author to the current user but does not set them as the author of the images they upload.

I figure there might be a way to add a function which finds the current user and then sets the author of the images they upload to that user.

Comment: OR is there a way to show only images media gallery linked to a certain post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_action("gform_user_registered", "image_author", 10, 4);
function image_author($user_id, $config, $entry, $user_pass) 
{
$post_id = $entry["post_id"];

$args = array(
'post_parent' => $post_id,
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'post_mime_type' => 'image'
);

$attachments = get_posts($args);
if($attachments) :
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) : setup_postdata($attachment);
       $the_post = array();
       $the_post['ID'] = $attachment->ID;
       $the_post['post_author'] = $user_id;

       wp_update_post( $the_post );

   endforeach;
endif;    

}
```

Comment: This finds the user ID after the user has registered and then sets them as the author of the files they uploaded while creating a post via gravity forms.

Comment: Tyler, if this solves your Question, please mark it as the correct Answer, so it doesn't hangs on the "Unanswered" category, thanks!